# Using transactions in laravel's eloquent

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have some forms that i want to commit to the database. However my code so far is in eloquent orm

```
$user->password = bcrypt($newPassword); 
$user->save()
```

I want to transform all code that updates,deletes or creates into the database to use database transactions. Is doing this

```
\DB::beginTransaction();
 $user->password = bcrypt($newPassword); 
 $user->save()
\DB::commit();
```

enough for me to have a transaction?.

Answer (score 1):

yes just add `try catch` or you can use automatic way:

```
DB::transaction(function ($user) {
   $user->password = bcrypt($newPassword); 
   $user->save()
});
```

**EDIT :** 
best practice to write manually transaction:

```
try {
   \DB::beginTransaction();
   $user->password = bcrypt($newPassword); 
   $user->save()
   \DB::commit();
}catch(\Exception $e){
   \DB::rollback();
}
```

Comment: For the automatic way, I think you'd actually want `DB::transaction(function () use  ($user) { ....`

Answer (score 0):

As you can found in the [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/database#database-transactions):

```
DB::transaction(function () {
    //Operations on db
});
```

It will automatically rollback if an exception is thrown inside the closure.

Comment: I saw that, but also saw this sneaky note at the bottom of the page http://imgur.com/a/WHk0F

Comment: @GeoffreyIsle The note means if there is something wrong making a query, including selecting data if something goes wrong and causes an exception all will rollback.

Comment: @Troyer It shouldn't be at the bottom. Its far too important to be placed last.